# Loop being executed but particular code being ignored in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe

TASK: To remove a set list of serial numbers amongst 1000+ from a csv.
Once a button on the GUI is clicked this body of code should execute:

```
refcsv = refFileAddress + "/examplefile.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(refcsv)
serialNums = ["123", "456", "789", "045"]

count = 0

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  try:
    serialNum = row [80]
  except:
    serialNum = 0
  for cnum in range(len(serialNums)):
    if(serialNum == serialNums[cnum]):
      df = df.drop(df.index[index])
      count = count + 1
      print("Serial number found. " + row[3] + " has been removed." )
      output("Number of people removed: " + str(count))


 if count == 0:
   output("Serial not found!")
```

Works well, it recognises the number of matching serial numbers and increments the count.
However, the `df = df.drop(df.index[index])` only works when I click the button for the number of serial numbers it recognises in the file.
E.g. if it finds 2 serial numbers in that file, I must click the button twice for it to remove those serial numbers.
So it's a matter of convenience to click the button once and remove all serials in one click. 
I've tried continue and I don't think break is appropriate in this case.

Comment: you don't show what's df in your code so its hard to answer...

Comment: My apologies, is that easier to understand?
It's a dataframe to allow columns and rows to be dropped and written back to the same file